# Flask: How can i use a context_processor from one blueprint in another blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I create a context_process in blueprint apple,

apple > views.py

```
@apple.context_processor
def eat_apple():
    return dict(fruit='apple')
```

If i were in another blueprint, how would i access @apple.context_processor, so that I can use the variable when i render a template?

Comment: `from apple.views import eat_apple`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use Bluepint.app_context_processor

e.g.

```
bp = Blueprint("myblueprint", __name__, url_prefix=None)                               

@myblueprint.app_context_processor                                                        
def inject_template_globals():                                                   
    company = Company.query.first()                                              
    return dict(company=company)
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of assigning it to the blueprint, assign it to the app.

```
@app.context_processor
def eat_apple():
    return dict(fruit='apple')
```

The *whole point* of having a blueprint-local context processor is that it only operates on that blueprint. So if that's not what you want, put it on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot reply to posts yet: I also was a bit struggling with this. My first solution worked but had some nasty side-effects with gunicorn.

What worked when using `flask run`, but what definitely will NOT WORK when using `gunicorn` or similar which is using multiple workers and your application is using ORM eg. sqlalchemy:
In my `create_app()` I added the following lines (after blueprints got registered)

```
app.app_context().push()
from appserver.utils import context_processors
```

Although this works with `gunicorn`, I got weird behavior with database-mutations. Only mutation that were done in a specific worker would show up on the front-end, but when you navigate away and back the that page it might be entirely possible the page is served by a different worker. I do not exactly know how this works - apparently the session is tied to a worker and so "sees" only those changes.

What does work:

The changes I had the make (thanks for the hint @user885983) were quite easy now:
In `create_app()` in replaced the lines above with the following and moved them where the other blueprints are being registered:

```
from appserver.utils import bp as utils_bp
app.register_blueprint(utils_bp)
```

and replaced `@bp.context_processor` with `@bp.app_context_processor`

I use this technique to load variables I need in all (jinja) templates like so (where backend is Class I created that handles a lot of common funtions:

```
@bp.app_context_processor
def get_menu_icons():
    menu_icon = backend.get_menu_icons()
    return dict(menu_icon=menu_icon)
```

This way I don't have to apply the variable to `render_template()` and still use it in the template: `{{ menu_icon.delete }}` eg.